# Display @media CSS to all screens, mobiles

Tags: css

Looking to display this to all devices at this 1024 pxwidth. Whether this includes Ipads, tablets or normal desktop screens or anythign with a device pixel ratio of 1 or above.

Do I need all screens adding to @media?

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #metaslider_223 > div > ul > li > img {
        width:132px !important;
    }

    #metaslider_223 > div > ul > li {
        width:132px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)` will evaluate to true for every device for 1024px width or less, no matter if it's a phone, tablet, apple watch or anything else

Comment: Everything has a pixel ratio of one or more?

Answer (score 0):

To answery your question, I would use "all" to ensure it covers everything (that's what I always do)

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #metaslider_223 > div > ul > li > img {
        width:132px !important;
    }

    #metaslider_223 > div > ul > li {
        width:132px !important;
    }
}
```